# If result document already exists, skip transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, transform, xproc

I just want to execute my transformations via XProc instead of using a batch/shell script.

my transformation process is a simple concatenation of in- and output documents - so the output of transformation 1 is the input of transformation 2. the output of transformation 2 is the input of transformation 3 and so on.

This code describes an example transformation:

```
<p:xslt name="Transformation1">
    <p:input port="source">
        <p:document href="input.xml"/>
    </p:input>
    <p:input port="stylesheet">
        <p:document href="trans1.xsl"/>
    </p:input>
    <p:input port="parameters">
        <p:empty/>
    </p:input>
</p:xslt>

<p:store href="output1.xml"/> 

<p:xslt name="Transformation2">
    <p:input port="source">
        <p:pipe step="Transformation1" port="result"/>
    </p:input>
    <p:input port="stylesheet">
        <p:document href="trans2.xsl"/>
    </p:input>
    <p:input port="parameters">
        <p:empty/>
    </p:input>
</p:xslt>

<p:store href="output2.xml"/>
```

It worked and additionally I get all temporary result documents to double check the functionality of each XSLT script. Processing complex and multiple transformations slows down things - because the XProc script always starts at the beginning. But I just want to fix something at transformation 4. Normally (using batch/shell) I just delete the output of transformation 4 , fix the XSLT script and skip all previous transformation on behalf of a if-test (e.g. if output3.xml exists goto transformation4). How to do so in a XProc script?

The XPath pattern is: `not(doc-available(‘output1.xml’))` - in compination with xsl:if it worked in XSLT. I tried to use a p:choose - but I didn't have an output-pipeline for p:otherwise and the process always fails. So I guess using p:choose wouldn't bring up the needed solution?

Any ideas?

Kind regards
Oliver

Comment: Why not first use a separate transformation to find if the file already exists.  Then the second transformation will run if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit awkward, because you want to skip the first xslt, but do need to get hold of its output. The only way to do that is to explicitly read output1.xml in case it exists. You could do it more or less like this:

```
<p:choose name="Transformation1">
    <p:when test="doc-available('output1.xml')">
        <p:output port="result">
            <p:pipe step="Transformation1-a" port="result"/>
        </p:output>
        <p:identity name="Transformation1-a">
            <p:input port="source">
                <p:document href="output1.xml"/>
            </p:input>
        </p:identity>
    </p:when>
    <p:otherwise>
        <p:output port="result">
            <p:pipe step="Transformation1-b" port="result"/>
        </p:output>
        <p:xslt name="Transformation1-b">
            <p:input port="source">
                <p:document href="input.xml"/>
            </p:input>
            <p:input port="stylesheet">
                <p:document href="trans1.xsl"/>
            </p:input>
            <p:input port="parameters">
                <p:empty/>
            </p:input>
        </p:xslt>

        <p:store href="output1.xml"/> 
    </p:otherwise>
</p:choose>

<p:xslt name="Transformation2">
    <p:input port="source">
        <p:pipe step="Transformation1" port="result"/>
    </p:input>
    <p:input port="stylesheet">
        <p:document href="trans2.xsl"/>
    </p:input>
    <p:input port="parameters">
        <p:empty/>
    </p:input>
</p:xslt>

<p:store href="output2.xml"/>
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks - it works. Unfortunately another problem came up. Because of the restriction of `p:document/@href` in terms of variables in path notations, I need to load the source:            `<p:load dtd-validate="false" name="indoc">
                <p:with-option name="href" select="concat($myPath, '/output1.xml')"/>
            </p:load>`. But using p:load doesn't allow me to define an output which leads me into an error messages, beause the pipelines are different.

Comment: @user1659553 Not a problem at all. The load already has a result by itself, just like indent. All you need to do is replace the identity with the load, preserving the name attribute, and it will work.

Comment: @Geert - again thanks for your help. I just added p:load to the p:otherwise routine (w/o removing p:output). I don't know why it didn't work while my first trial. Anyway, you have helped to understand XProc a bit more.